# Django. I can't understand the error 404 wheb displaying products from the catalog

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-views, django-templates

I'm making a catalog, I can't understand why products are not displayed by catalog categories, it gives an error 404. The sections in the catalog work as they should. Here is the code:

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse


class Catalog_text(models.Model):
    text_left = models.TextField('Text1')
    text_right = models.TextField('Text2')
    signature = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name="Signature")

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Text1'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Text2'

class Catalog(models.Model):

    sections = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True, verbose_name="Name")
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/catalog/')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=150, db_index=True, unique=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('sections',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)
        verbose_name = 'catalog'
        verbose_name_plural = 'catalogs'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sections

    def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('catalog', kwargs={"slug": self.slug})



class Category(models.Model):
    catalog = models.ForeignKey(Catalog, related_name='catalog', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                 verbose_name='Select a directory'
                                 )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150, db_index=True, verbose_name="Name") 
    img = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/catalog/')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)
        verbose_name = 'Category'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Categories'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
            return reverse('catalog-detail', kwargs={"slug": self.slug})


class Product(models.Model):
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, related_name='category', on_delete=models.CASCADE,
                                verbose_name='Select a category'
                                )
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True,unique=True, null=True, verbose_name="Название")
    text = models.TextField('Текст')
    url = models.CharField(max_length=255, db_index=True, verbose_name="Link to the website")
    pdf = models.FileField(upload_to='pdf/')
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200, db_index=True, unique=True, null=True)
    
    class Meta:
        ordering = ('name',)
        index_together = (('id', 'slug'),)
        verbose_name = 'Product'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Products'
    
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('product-detail', kwargs={"slug": self.slug})


class Gallery(models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='img/catalog/')
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='images')
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Gallery'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Galleries'
```

urls.py

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

from . import views

urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.CatalogView.as_view(), name='catalog'),
    path('<slug>/', views.CatalogDetailViews.as_view(), name='catalog-detail'),
    path('product/<slug>', views.ProductDetailViews.as_view(), name='product-detail')
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, get_object_or_404
from .models import Catalog_text, Catalog, Category, Product
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView

class CatalogView(ListView):
    model = Catalog
    template_name = 'catalog/catalog.html'
    context_object_name = 'catalog'

class CatalogDetailViews(ListView):
    model = Category
    template_name = 'catalog/catalog-detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'category'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(CatalogDetailViews, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['cat'] = Catalog.objects.all()
        return context

    def get_queryset(self):   
        category = get_object_or_404(Catalog, slug__iexact=self.kwargs.get('slug'))
        queryset = category.catalog.all()
        return queryset


class ProductDetailViews(DetailView):
    model = Product
    template_name = 'catalog/product-detail.html'
    context_object_name = 'product'
```

In the template:

```
{% for cat in category %}
                    <div class="room-item catalog_items">
                        <ul class="hover-effect-cover">
                            <li>
                              <img src="{{ cat.img.url }}" alt="">
                              
                              <div class="effect-to-top">
                                <h3>{{ cat.name }}</h3>
                                <p></p>
                                <a href="{% url 'product-detail' cat.id %}" class="button">more detailed</a>
                              </div>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    {% endfor %}
```

Let's say I'm in the admin panel category test and product for this category product1, the link in the template turns out to be catalog/product/test and, accordingly, gives 404, but if I correct the link in the address bar to catalog/product/product1, then everything will open as it should (product description).

Answer (score 0):

I guess instead of this (passing **category id** whereas product-detail url pattern expects **product slug**)

```
{% url 'product-detail' cat.id %}
```

you need this

```
{% url 'catalog-detail' cat.slug %}
```

But if you wanted to list all the products then you need nested loop for products per given category.

upd

You cannot get to "product details" just having "category id". From the perspective of category you can get to "category details" or retrieve **list** of category products. If you want to display list of products per category then you need something like

```
{% for cat in category %}
    {% for prod in cat.product_set.all %}
```

and only after that refer to the specific product page

```
{% url 'product-detail' prod.slug %}
```

Comment: I changed it to slug, there are no changes, the same error

Comment: different url pattern name also. or nested loop.

Comment: I don't quite understand you

Comment: In this case, no links are displayed on the page
(there can only be one product in one category)

Comment: "something like" was supposed to mean "put the real query or method here". updated. please try now.

Comment: No, that doesn't work either.